# How does Entity Framework know how to generate SQL for a specific backend and can it be changed? Dreaded APPLY issue

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I have an application that is using Entity Framework (4.1 I think). I am currently using Oracle ODAC 112030 32bit. I have two machines, one using .Net Framework 4.0 and the other using version 4.5 (4.0's replacement). When I run my web application and execute a particular Linq-To-Entities query on the 4.0 machine the query runs fine, but when I run the 4.5 machine the query fails with the Oracle error **{"ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"} inner exception {"Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 does not support APPLY"}**

My question is, Is there anyway to tell EF not to use APPLY? 
If there is not, is there a workaround for FirstOrDefault() in a single Linq query?

Microsoft has listed known issues with EF with regards to APPLY
[EF Known Issues 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273.aspx)

Blurb from link above

> Targeting the Correct SQL Server Version
>   The Entity Framework targets the Transact-SQL query based on the SQL Server version that is specified in the ProviderManifestToken attribute of the Schema element in the storage model (.ssdl) file. This version might differ from the version of the actual SQL Server you are connected to. For example, if you are using SQL Server 2005, but your ProviderManifestToken attribute is set to 2008, the generated Transact-SQL query might not execute on the server. For example, a query that uses the new date time types that were introduced in SQL Server 2008 will not execute on earlier versions of the SQL Server. If you are using SQL Server 2005, but your ProviderManifestToken attribute is set to 2000, the generated Transact-SQL query might be less optimized, or you might get an exception that says that the query is not supported. For more information, see the CROSS and OUTER APPLY Operators section, earlier in this topic.
>   Certain database behaviors depend on the compatibility level set to the database. If your ProviderManifestToken attribute is set to 2005 and your SQL Server version is 2005, but the compatibility level of a database is set to "80" (SQL Server 2000), the generated Transact-SQL will be targeting SQL Server 2005, but might not execute as expected due to the compatibility level setting. For example, you might lose ordering information if a column name in the ORDER BY list matches a column name in the selector.

In my case I only see "Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="10.2" since I'm using Oracle.

Comment: In the machine where runs framework 4.5 you will need to install ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20) for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework is now open sourced at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework, so you can read the code to answer your own question.